# JavaScript: How is Object implemented such that new Object({}) and Object({}) are the same

Tags: javascript, object

In JavaScript, I can write:

```
x = new Object({ a: 3 })
```

and I will have `x = { a: 3 }`

Similarly, I can write

```
x = Object({ a: 3 })
```

and I will have `x = { a: 3 }` again.

My question is: How is `Object` implemented to satisfy both these ways of calling it? In the first scenario, it will receive a fresh `this`, while in the second it will receive the global object.

My best guess is something like:

```
var Object = function(obj) {
    var global = (function() { return this; })();
    if (global == this) { // I am called as a regular function
        // Create a copy of obj, potentially like this
        return { ...obj };
    } else { // I am called via new
        // Copy all fields of obj onto this
        // not sure what the best way to do this is.
    }
}
```

Comment: It _really_ seems like something you _really_ don't wanna do though!

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Totally agree! I am mostly curious how it's done :)

Comment: I get that. For educational purposes everything is okay. Just felt like it should be mentioned!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is [in the specificaton](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-value):

> When **Object** function is called with optional argument *value*, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If NewTarget is neither **undefined** nor the active function, then
>
>    - Return ? OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget,  "%ObjectPrototype%").
> 2. If value is **null**, **undefined** or not supplied, return ObjectCreate(%ObjectPrototype%).
> 3. Return ! ToObject(*value*).

Step #1 is about what the code should do when the call is happening as part of creating something that inherits from `Object`, so we can ignore that step for your question.

Step #2 doesn't apply because you're passing in `value` and it's neither `null` nor `undefined`.

So Step #3 is what happens: It uses the [`ToObject`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-toobject) operation to do type conversion to turn `value` into an object. Since `value` is already an object, that's a no-op, and the result is the same object you passed in. The `new Object` part of `new Object({a: 1})` is completely unnecessary.

> In the first scenario, it will receive a fresh `this`, while in the second it will receive the global object.

As you can see from the spec steps above, `Object` doesn't use `this` at all.

Comment: I find it interesting that just above the section you quoted the spec says "When called as a constructor it creates a new ordinary object.". When I run `var x = {}; console.log( new Object(x) === x );` I get `true` (which I do expect from the steps you posted), which seems to contradict the prior statement I referenced.

Comment: @Paulpro: Yeah, that threw me too. That sentence is true only when you don't pass in an argument (or you pass `null` or `undefined`). It's arguably false otherwise. Other sections are a bit more clear about calling built-ins either as constructors or as functions ([`Array`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array-objects), for instance).

Answer (score -1):

It's simple as that

```js
function Object(obj) {
  return obj;
}
```

When you call it as function it inherits its parent's scope that is `window`.
Buy when you initialize it as a class, the function itself is the constructor that has its own scope `this`.

And it's not creating a new instance with copied properties as you can see in this example:

```js
var a = {a : 3};
var b = new Object(a);
var c = Object(a);

console.log(a === b);
console.log(a === c);
```

As @user2357112 specified that it's not that simple here is a more close to Object functionality:

```js
function Object(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'number') {
    return new Number(value);
  }
  
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return new String(value);
  }
  
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    return {};
  } 
  
  return value
}

var a = new Object(undefined);

console.log(new Object(1));
console.log(new Object('sad'));
console.log(new Object([]));
console.log(new Object({}));
console.log(new Object(null));
console.log(new Object());
```

Comment: It's not *that* simple, because `Object(1)` is an object, not `1`.

Comment: @user2357112 as the author specified, his question was why he has 2 different scopes when executing as a class and as a function. If the author wants I can try to replicate the whole Object functionality

Answer (score -1):

I think it is something like

```
function Object(obj) {
  If (this instanceof Object) {
       return Object.assign(this, ...obj)
     }
  return new Object(obj);
 }
```

Comment: I feel that even if I'd call `x = Object({ a: 3})` I would pass the test `this instanceof Object` as `this` would be the global object.

Comment: @RaduSzasz `Object` is a native object anyway and need not be implemented in JavaScript, but if you're interested this trick could work in strict mode: `function Object ( ) { "use strict"; if ( ! this ) return Object.assign(this, ...obj); ... }`.